# Couldn't find <object> without an ID rails 3.0.1

Tags: activerecord, model, view, ruby-on-rails-3

Unfortunately, this is my second post in as many days.  So the application worked fine with mysql and rails 3.0.3 but I found out that I needed to use MSSQL so I had to downgrade rails to 3.0.1.

In a nutshell, I copied the show.html.erb as show2.html.erb and created a new method which is a copy of the show method.  Then I created a route match.

my controller

```
class fathersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @father= Father.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @father}
    end
  end

  def show2
    @father= Father.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @father}
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :fathers do
    match '/show2' => 'fathers#show2'
    resources :kids
end
```

when I call

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/father/1
```

I get the show view but when I call

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/father/1/show2
```

I get the following error

```
Couldn't find father without an ID
```

The request Parameters come back as

```
{"father_id"=>"1"}
```

so I know that the problem is that the app is passing the id as father_id but how do I fix it?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. You're trying to use a non-resourceful route on a route that actually should be resourceful.
2. It looks like you're trying to send `/show2` to a controller named `hospitals`, when your action is actually specified on the `fathers` controller.

This should do the trick:

```
resources :fathers do
  get :show2, :on => :member
  resources :kids
end
```

You can also write the above as:

```
resources :fathers do
  member do
    get :show2
  end

  resources :kids
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but now it is passing the correct variable but now I get the error I was getting yesterday   undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass so now it doesn't see the father class as being legitimate

Comment: That sounds like a different issue to me--as in, not a routing problem. Could you please open a new question with the relevant controller, models and views?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I had forgotten and taken the method out of my controller.